# Best practices to pass a subquery to a dynamic query in Python with Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm currently working with Python and Pandas to query data from my databse. I have one query to get some customer information (this is obviously not the real query, it's simplified without joins etc.):

```
def customer_query(con, date):
    stmt = """
    SELECT
        first_name
        last_name
        dob
    FROM
        customer
    """
    return pd.read_sql(
        stmt,
        con
    )
```

*I do it with pandas so that I can easily export the dataset to csv without any hassle.*

The requirements changed and I need to generate two different datasets based on circumstances around the customer. 
The original query still holds, we still need first_name, last_name etc, so I don't want to create two entirely separate queries.
I want to add a where-clause to my query like so:

```
def customer_query(con, date):
    stmt = """
    SELECT
        first_name
        last_name
        dob
    FROM
        customer
    where id in (:sub)
    """
    return pd.read_sql(
        stmt,
        con,
        params={"sub": "SELECT customer_id FROM different_table_1"},
    )
```

I cannot just put the subquery in the statement with a parameter. What I wish to do is put the subquery as a parameter.
This way I could pass the subquery as an argument and generate two different datasets. That doesn't work with pandas though.
The only thing I can come up with is to execute the subquery on it's own, grab the customer ids from it and pass those to my "customer_query" function. This isn't as nice as executing everything in one SQL statement, but I don't have any other idea. I also refrain from the idea to build the sql statement with f strings or something.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I'm connection to an Oracle DB and the "con" object is a cx_Oracle connection.
Apparently my thought of solution is not valid since cx_Oracle does not really support passing a list as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off creating two queries so the optimizer tunes each one.  Like everything "it depends".  How often will they run?  Does the connection remain open (there is also the statement cache to think about), etc, etc.

In Oracle SQL, bind values are not used to build up SQL statements (hence their security benefits).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. They would run once a day, I just don't like the idea of creating two queries since I'd have to change both if another customer attribute would be needed in the resultset.

Comment: You may be interested in https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause

Comment: Yes, thank you I already saw that. I'm gonna be using a slight variation of the following for now: tableWhiteList = ['employees', 'departments']
tableName = getTableName() #  get the table name from user input
if tableName not in tableWhiteList:
    raise Exception('Invalid table name')
sql = 'select * from ' + tableName